# How can I count multiple heating?

Tags: grammar, nouns, uncountable-nouns

I found the following sentence:

> There is too much heating.

According to my dictionary, *heating* is an uncountable noun, so you cannot say *heatings*.

However, it is possible that you have more than one heating in your house. For example you have one in your room, and the other in your living room.

In this case, how can you express it? I think when you express *two furniture*, it should be *two pieces of furniture*, but how about the case of *heating*?

Comment: The word for a physical device that radiates heat is "heater," which is countable. You can say "there are too many heaters."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With respect to physical devices, you can't have one or more *heatings* in your house.

In terms of overall heat, you could say:

> It is too hot.
>   There is too much heat.
>   The temperature is too high.

In terms of "more than one heating," you could say:

> There are too many sources of heat.
>   There are too many heaters.

---

It's possible that the word *heating* could be used in a nonstandard way to describe an event:

> "Everybody come to my igloo tonight. We're going to have ourselves a good old fashioned heating to warm the place up."

Assuming that the word is being used in that specific context, it actually would be possible to turn it into a plural:

> "You need to stop holding all of those heatings. Your igloo won't be able to take it much longer and will melt."

But that's something very specific (and nonstandard) and it doesn't apply to physical heating devices.

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided any context.  But it's possible that the author of those words meant that something had been heated too much.  Sometimes speakers will say "There is" to mean "in this situation".

> You can see why the metal has fatigued. There is too much heating.

The speaker would mean something like "the metal has been subjected to too much heat".

There, **heating** is understood to be a process.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't have different *heating* in different rooms. You have different *heating outlets* in different rooms. An outlet is simply the place from where the air comes out.

So, if you are talking about two or more rooms, you can say that we have multiple heater outlets in our house.

Here is the example of [heater outlets.](http://www.heateroutlet.com/productcart/pc/home.asp)

In your question, *too much heating* simply means that there is more heating and someone needs to reduce the temperature from the heateres installed.